Unable to Use Local Models for Autogen Agents Due to OpenAI API Key Error
I'm trying to use the Autogen library with local Huggingface models instead of using the OpenAI API. However, I'm encountering an issue where I receive the following error:
OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure the Autogen library to use local Huggingface models? Are there any specific settings or modifications needed to bypass the API key requirement?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
